# M-x compile better final state

Tags: emacs

When I say `M-x compile` the `make` program is typically called.  When finished, the buffer `*compilation*` is often left in an undesirable state: half of the window is left empty (probably expecting some more output). With `C-l C-l` I can move to last line in the buffer to the bottom of the window - so I see more of the actual compilation process.

Is  there a clean way to configure `compile` such that the window will always show the maximal number of lines - at least at the end?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I came up with (put it in your `.emacs`).

```
(defun compilation-redisplay (proc msg)
  "Scroll the current window to fit the tail of the buffer
in. This only fires if `compilation-scroll-output' is true"
  (when (memq (process-status proc) '(exit signal))
    (let ((buffer (process-buffer proc)))
      ;; Check that the buffer hasn't already been killed
      (unless (null (buffer-name buffer))
        (with-current-buffer buffer
          ;; Check we're at the bottom of the buffer and that we're there
          ;; because compile.el put us there
          (when (and compilation-scroll-output
                     (= (point) (point-max)))
            (with-selected-window (get-buffer-window)
              ;; This logic is pinched from recenter-top-bottom (window.el)
              (recenter
               (- -1 (min (max 0 scroll-margin)
                          (truncate (/ (window-body-height) 4.0))))))))))))

(advice-add 'compilation-sentinel :after #'compilation-redisplay)
```

The idea is that it runs when the compilation process finishes. It then does a little bit of checking to make sure that there is a sensible buffer, that `compilation-scroll-output` is set, and that point is at the bottom of the buffer (you don't want stuff jumping around if you have a long compilation process and you've already started poring over the output). Finally, the recenter call is stolen from the code in `recenter-top-bottom`.

Comment: From `with-current-buffer` on: isn't this what `C-l` does directly?

Comment: From "This logic" on: yes. Which is why I wrote that comment. The previous part is to make sure that we're in the right place, as I wrote in my answer. Can you explain why this answer doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: A more compact (and marginally less efficient) version would help understanding this also after some time.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you're asking for. The code after the "This logic is pinched" comment comes from the middle of the `recent-top-bottom` function, so it's not possible to call out to something to do it for us. I don't think I've done anything verbose for efficiency.